# How to dynamically create an array using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic

i have array in this form

```
['203,448', '204,297', '204,448', '205,297', '230,448', '231,297', '24,448', '24,297','203,548', '204,548', '204,548' ]
```

Desire Output :

```
0:['203,448',  '204,448', '230,448','24,448', ]
1: [ '204,297',  '205,297', '231,297', '24,297']
2: ['203,548', '204,548', '204,548']
```

I want to sepreate Elements on the base of 2 featur
i.e 203,**448**
and 204 ,**297**

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: i try to different using 2nd Feature
foreach feature in layer_featureinfo
     if features_result[1]== 297 :
  else if features_result[1]== 448

Comment: Which language is this?? :)

Comment: I tried in both js and Python
This is JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a hash table for same second part of the string and collect same items in an array.

```js
var data = ['203,448', '204,297', '204,448', '205,297', '230,448', '231,297', '24,448', '24,297', '203,548', '204,548', '204,548'],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        var key = a.split(',')[1];
        if (!hash[key]) {
            hash[key] = [];
            r.push(hash[key]);
        }
        hash[key].push(a);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For putting only the first part, you could use splitting array

```js
var data = ['203,448', '204,297', '204,448', '205,297', '230,448', '231,297', '24,448', '24,297', '203,548', '204,548', '204,548'],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        var s = a.split(',');
        if (!hash[s[1]]) {
            hash[s[1]] = [];
            r.push(hash[s[1]]);
        }
        hash[s[1]].push(s[0]);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks A lot   Can You guide lets say if we want 

Result holds [
  [
    "203",
    "204",
    "230",
    "24"
  ],
  [
    "204",
    "205",
    "231",
    "24"
  ],
  [
    "203",
    "204",
    "204"
  ]
]
I try but i not work I may use this in some other case

Comment: Mine Pleasure Mam & Yes  i found the same   Just 1 minute ago Thanks